# Gradle Tool Bar not showing project root

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-toolbar, gradle-task

I have to extract the SHA key but in Gradle tool bar task is not shwing[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86v3w.png)

Comment: try to sync the project again with sync button

Comment: issue still un resolved